# GROUP BY selection with filling up missing times

Tags: php, mysql, sql

While I was working on a PHP code to fix the issue, I came across the question if my problem might be fixable with MySQL. This is my SQL until now:

```
SELECT sec_to_time(time_to_sec(checkin_time)- time_to_sec(checkin_time)%(15*60)) AS intervals, 
COUNT(checkin_id) AS checkin_total, 
SUM(checkin_guestno) AS guest_total 
FROM gl_checkin 
WHERE `checkin_entry` IN (SELECT entry_id FROM gl_entry WHERE entry_event = XXX)
GROUP BY intervals";
```

As you can see, I have a checkin database where there are times of people checking in. Counting and summing up the guests as well. At the end I use GROUP BY intervals to group my results per 15 minutes so I can make a nice graph of it. This is where my question comes in, the results can be:

- 19:00:00   (21  43)
- 19:15:00   (18  38)
- 19:45:00   (19  36)

As you can see there is gap between the second and third result of 15 minutes. Is there a way I can give back the following result without using PHP?

- 19:00:00   (21  43)
- 19:15:00   (18  38)
- 19:30:00   (0  0)
- 19:45:00   (19  36)

Using PHP is not a big problem at all but it would be awesome to do this all in sql. Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a table that contains all the 15-minute times of the day. Then `LEFT JOIN` this table with your query.

Comment: @Barmar That's not a bad idea at all. The only thing is that I only want to fill up missing spaces. Not the whole day. You have an idea for a query with that?

Comment: When selecting from the time table, add a `WHERE` clause that only selects times between the minimum and maximum in the checkin table.

Comment: Perfect! So simple, yet so effective! Thanks @Barmar